# Insert Contact then auto create an opportunity in NPSP

Tags: apex, account, relationships, insert, npsp

Good day everyone,

My problem is something related on how NPSP works. Suppose I have 2 group of data, one is CONTACT and one is OPPORTUNITY. What I want to achieve is that I want to insert those 2 data at the same time. We know that when we create a CONTACT,the NPSP will automatically create an ACCOUNT which is related to the CONTACT. What I want to achieve is that, I want to get the accountID in order to put in my OPPORTUNITY data.

The idea I have at the moment, is that I have to insert the CONTACT and after that I query the contact data(including the ACCOUNTID) base on the CONTACT inserted ID then get put the ACCOUNTID in my opportunity then insert the OPPORTUNITY. But is there any easier and more effecient way to do that ? Please help.

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

There is a workbook for importing data into the NPSP using the NPSP Data Importer which provides exactly the functionality you're requesting.

https://powerofus.force.com/articles/Resource/NPSP-Administrators-Guide-to-Importing-Donor-Data

In the future, you'll probably get a faster response to NPSP specific questions in the Power of Us Hub (https://powerofus.salesforcefoundation.org) where you can find other user and partners with specific knowledge of the NPSP.